# jquery add and remove class working inconsistently

Tags: jquery, addclass

I am making a to-do list app. When the user clicks the checkmark to add the class `.done`, then the text in the `<span>` should gray out, and the checkmark should fill in and turn black. If they uncheck it, the text should return to black and the checkmark to it's unchecked state.

This works until there is more than one item, and then it works inconsistently. Sometimes the checkmarks won't do anything when checked, sometimes the text stays grayed out but the checkmark returns to unchecked. I am a beginner at jQuery (as I'm sure will be obvious when you see my code), and this is my first post here. I have searched and I am not finding information I haven't tried. I tried to make sure the class is removed before adding a new one.

Here is the js:

```
$(".checkmark").on("click", function() {
      // alert($(this));

      if ($(this).attr('data-icon') == '\ue603') {
        $(this).attr('data-icon', '\ue600').removeClass("notdone").addClass("done")
      }
      else {
        $(this).attr('data-icon', '\ue603').removeClass("done").addClass("notdone")
      };

      if ($("span.checkmark").is(".done")) {
        // $("#list").prev(".list_item").addClass("grayedout")
        $(this).next().addClass("grayedout")
        // alert(this);
       }
       else {
        $(this).next().removeClass("grayedout")
       };

    });

    $(".delete").on("click", function() {
        // alert("delete me!");
        $(this).closest("li").remove();
      });

 });
    var addItems =function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();

        //make sure the input isn't blank
        if($("#item").val()=='') {
            alert("please enter some sh!t to get done");
          }

        else {
          //add list item 
          $("#list ul").append('<li><span aria-hidden="true" data-icon= '+ uncheck +' class="checkmark"></span><span class="list_item">'+ $('#item').val() + '</span><span aria-hidden="true" data-icon="&#xe601;" class="delete"></span></li>');              
          // clear input box
          $("#item").val("");
           };
    };
```

Here is a link to the page: http://eak000.github.io/todo/
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the line

```
if ($("span.checkmark").is(".done")) {
```

it checks whether the first `checkmark` element has the class `done`, instead you need to check whether the currently clicked `checkmark` has the class `done` so

```
if ($(this).is(".done")) {
//or if ($(this).hasClass("done")) {
```

---

You have another problem in the way in which you are adding the click handler, you are adding the click handler inside another click handler(the add button) which also could lead to problems.

The reason you might have done that is to handle dynamic elements, but the solution is to use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/), so instead of adding the click handler in the `$("#item").on("keypress", function(e) {` handler try to add the below in the dom ready handler

```
$('.list').on("click", '.checkmark', function () {
    // alert($(this));

    var isDone = $(this).hasClass("done");
    $(this).attr('data-icon', isDone ? '\ue600' : '\ue603').toggleClass("notdone", isDone).toggleClass("done", !isDone)

    $(this).next().toggleClass("grayedout", !isDone)

});

$('.list').on("click", '.delete', function () {
    // alert("delete me!");
    $(this).closest("li").remove();
});
```

Comment: THANK YOU!!! That seems to have done the trick!! And thank you for the clear explanation...I get it now.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that second issue. I had a lot of trouble with the icon fonts working properly and I knew what I was doing was clumsy. This worked wonderfully, though I never would have come up with it on my own at this point in my learning. :-) Thanks again!!

Comment: Event delegation is so necessary. Probably the least understood aspect of DOM manipulation.